# get full list of devices from arp -a command

Tags: batch-file, networking, arp

I made a (very) simple batch file:

```
@echo off
:start
arp -a | findstr 20-7c-8f-3f-03-9c
cls
if %errorlevel% GEQ 1 (
echo The device is offline
Echo Device is offline at %time% on %date%. >> log.txt
) else (
echo The device is online.
Echo Device is online at %time% on %date%. >> log.txt
)
timeout 3 >nul /nobreak
goto start
```

While this works fine and dandy, it doesn't work if said device is not listed, ie Phones.

Here's what I mean.

All of the devices connected to my router don't show up in the `arp -a` output.   Say the Mac address of my ipod is `18:E7:F4:86:75:9F`.  Is there some alternative way to detect if it is on the LAN?  Or should I just other software.  I like using this, and having it always running in the background.  It would be an extremely useful tool.  I could tell when my parents get home, or just if anybody I know is at my house.  It would serve as a lazy security program.  Just thinking of some ideas and potential this could have.

Am I just better off using Nmap?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a roundabout method to the issue.  It doesn't necessarily solve my problem, it just makes *my* program work.  It uses a tool called [Wireless Network Watcher](http://nirsoft.net/utils/wireless_network_watcher.html), and uses its command line features.  I basically print everything on the programs screen to file.txt, and then I scan file.txt for the mac address.  It takes around seven seconds to cycle through this whole process, but it gets the job done.

Code:

```
@echo off
echo gathering info . . .
:start
if exist info.txt del info.txt
wnetwatcher.exe /stext info.txt
:loop
if exist "info.txt" (
goto aaa
)
timeout 2 >nul /nobreak
goto loop

:aaa
cls
find info.txt "18-E3-A4-86-75-9C" >nul
if %errorlevel% GEQ 1 (
color c0
echo.
echo.

echo.    Cole's iPod is offline.
) else (
color a0
echo.
echo.
echo.    Cole's iPod is online.
)
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Refreshing (7s)
goto start
```

It would still be nice to have another answer, i.e., why does my ipod not show up?

Comment: you shouldn't need a temporary file: `wnetwatcher.exe |find "18-E3-A4-86-75-9C" >nul && echo online || echo offline` should do.

Comment: Wnetwatcher.exe starts the GUI program.  There is no way to have the results in a command output.